# How to send file in PHP 5.05 using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a file in PHP 5.0.5 using cURL but cannot do it. It returns bool(false). I can send it using command line but I need to send it within my PHP code.

THis is the commandline code, 
curl --data-binary @employee_extract.txt https://testserver.com/testapp.aspx --proxy http://111.111.11.11:8080

This is the successful returned message,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Status>
  <result>ok</result>
  <size>192</size>
  <id>20190409134142_C12040C53BCC4AC6B4A09E1BC476D262.txt</id>
  <message>
    <p>file</p>
    <p>No xmldoc posted, saving stream.</p>
  </message>
</Status>
```

PHP Code:

```
$url = 'https://testserver.com/testapp.aspx';
$proxy = '111.111.11.11:8080';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

// send a file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$args['file'] = "@employee_extract.txt;filename=file;type=text/plain"   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
echo $curl_scraped_page;
var_dump($curl_scraped_page);
```

actual results: var_dump($curl_scraped_page) returns bool(false)
expected results: a successful message

Comment: "I'm trying to send a file in PHP 5.0.5" I hope you're joking. https://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: Yeah, almost 15 years old.

Comment: Have you used [curl_errno()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to check the specific reason for the failure?

Comment: Thanks Patrick! curl_errno() helped me to figure out the issue. I ended up adding this curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a version of PHP that reached end-of-life in 2005, nearly 15 years ago. Your problem is probably related to this. For instance, your example URL uses HTTPS -- it's possible that the version of curl embedded in your vintage PHP interpreter is incompatible with the HTTPS configuration of the web server it is connecting to.

(Even if "5.0.5" is a typo and you actually meant PHP 5.5, that version reached end-of-life in 2016.)

Update your system to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: I agree that I need to update my PHP version. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I agree that I need to update my PHP version. I used curl_errno() to determine what the specific issue was. Thank you everyone for your help!